# MinioClient thread safe

Tags: object-storage, minio

I am trying to user minio java sdk. In multi thread environment, can we share MinioClient object between multiple threads simultaneously. Is MinioClient java client object thread safe.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, MinioClient is thread-safe

Source: https://github.com/minio/minio-java/issues/975 . So,  MinioClient is thread-safe and they have a functional test runs on every Pull Request.

Comment: I try in my code and it is working. I have not done heavy load test but it is working for me