# Why MinioClient multi-threaded upload, the more threads, the slower the upload?

Tags: java, spring-boot, minio

There are a large number of pictures in our business that need to upload MinIO. In order to improve the upload speed, I used multiple threads, but found that the more threads, the slower the upload speed.

I analyzed it and suspected that it was because MinIOClient was a single instance that multithreading could not be used to optimize upload performance, so I created multiple MinIOClient to improve the upload performance of multithreading. The optimized code is as follows:

```
import com.pe.pe_service.service.ISysModuleConfigService;
import io.minio.MinioClient;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

@Slf4j
public class MinioUtils {

    private static final Integer DEFAULT_MINIO_CLIENT_COUNT = 10;

    public static CopyOnWriteArrayList<MinioClient> MINIO_LIST = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<MinioClient>();

    public static AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public static MinioClient minioClient(String address, String accessKey, String secretKey) {
        try {
            return new MinioClient.Builder()
                    .endpoint(address)
                    .credentials(accessKey, secretKey)
                    .build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("minioClient address[{}] accessKey[{}] secretKey[{}] 初始化异常", address, accessKey, secretKey);
        }
        return null;
    }


    public static void initMinioList(String address, String accessKey, String secretKey) {
        for (int i = 0; i < MinioUtils.getMinioClientCount(); i++) {
            MINIO_LIST.add(MinioUtils.minioClient(address, accessKey, secretKey));
        }
    }

    public static MinioClient getMinioClient() {
        int i = index.get();
        i = (++i) % MinioUtils.getMinioClientCount();
        index.set(i);
        return MINIO_LIST.get(i);
    }

    public static Integer getMinioClientCount() {
        return DEFAULT_MINIO_CLIENT_COUNT;
    }


}
```

But there is no effect, I need help!!! how can I improve the upload performance of minio multithreading?

MinIO is also deployed in the same environment, so I don't think the network is a bottleneck.

Now no matter how many threads I use, the upload rate is around 100 images. per second

Comment: Multithreading does not ‘optimize performance’ of an upload. There is only one network.

Comment: A single thread is probably fast enough to saturate your upload link. If you use more threads then the upload data rate is divided between these threads, meaning that each thread gets less upload data rate.

Comment: Also you don't need to create multiple MinIO clients for multi-threading (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59788343/minioclient-thread-safe, https://github.com/minio/minio-java/issues/975)

Comment: Thanks,I know. But I want to know what is really limiting my upload speed, disk, network, CPU, memory resources are sufficient...

Comment: @ThomasKläger has already answered that.